# How to deal with IE8 Compatibility View in a user-friendly way?

Tags: usability, gui-design, browser

I'm struggling to understand how IE8 Compatibility View works.

Sometimes we find some bugs on IE8 Compatibility View that cannot be found on IE8 and other browsers.

We wrote a message telling the users to change to IE8 if they are in Compatibility View, but that does not seem very user-friendly at all. So, what would be the best way to approach that?

We are wondering if there is a way of forcing IE8 to never go into Compatibility View and without damaging the UX. Will it break the page? Will it damage accessibility?

Are there any other user-friendly solutions?

Cheers!

Comment: I've used the `x-ua-compatible` http-equiv attribute to boot people out of compatability mode since IE8, infuriatingly, assumes intranet domains should be compatible view'd, which was a problem for internal sites despite everyone having IE8 or higher. Not sure that fixes manually set compatibility view though.

Comment: @BenBrocka, so this will only happen in intranets? Because that is what I said, that the 2% that were using the site in Compatibility Mode were the staff. But I felt it was a hunch, did not feel confident to write that down.

Comment: If it's being treated link an Intranet (not 100% sure how IE detects that) then yeah that might be the only problem. Here if we accessed the site from `customdns/site` it would work but `www.publicurl.com/site` it would work. I don't have stats but I can't imagine compatibility view is over 1% without IE auto applying it.

Comment: @BenBrocka: IE determines that based on the rules in the Intranet Security Zone in the preferences (the main default is if the domain name is a single word/computer name). You can see if it's being applied by looking in the bottom right of the window to see if it's being evaluated as being in the  "Intranet" zone. [Here's an overly technical explanation direct from the Microsoft IE team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/06/05/the-local-intranet-security-zone.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You can use...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

...to disable compatibility mode (which I loving call "broken mode") and force the user into using the most cutting edge IE rending that their browser has. 
More tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348959/how-to-disable-compatibility-view-in-ie

I would encourage you to consider trying to nudge users of old browsers to upgrade. [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) adds this line to the top of the body:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Oh does IE edge not break if a new version comes out? I was using IE=9 then it broke with 10

Comment: There are risks with edge and risks with a specific version. Yes, it's possible that future versions of IE might break your styles or code. But if you set a fixed value for a version of IE, then you risk leaving your users in the past once new versions come out. The solution to both: just keep your site up-to-date (sometimes easier said than done).

Comment: @Luke FYI the devs have fixed this issue. It seems like it was slightly more complicated than just using the meta. I think this article explains the solution to the problem we had http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817573.aspx Cheers!